# How can I customize the `x` icon on a `Creatable`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I would like to change the `x` icon found on each tag's icon to my own image.

Does [react-select](/questions/tagged/react-select) support this?

[image]

Comment: And the code was in no place to be found...

Comment: I don't see how a code snippet would help this question.

Comment: Why don't you just create some css for the `.Select-clear` class ? (assuming I understand this question)

Comment: @3Dos I want to customize the `x` on each tag, not the clear all button. Will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in pure CSS:

```
.Select-value-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.Select-value-icon::after {
  visibility: visible;
  content: url('/img/delete-tag-icon.png');
}
```

The idea is that you hide the default `x` using `visibility: hidden` but then generate an extra element containing the custom image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs and after looking in the source code, you'll find that there's no render prop for [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/lib/Value.js). @`renderRemoveIcon`. You could still modify it through css, though not as flexible as having your own renderer.